# Создать .bat файл

Tags: bat

Нужна помощь в создании `.bat`, который выполняет следующую функцию:
В браузере `Chrome` открывает ссылку `www.123.ru`, через 5 секунд закрывает её и открывает `www.456.ru`, через 5 секунд закрывает её и снова открывает первую ссылку, потом опять вторую... И так 77 раз.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это полностью можно реализовать?

Comment: Никак?.. Закрыть вкладку в браузере это тяжело. Но можете использовать например curl. А зачем это?

Comment: Для этого лучше подойдет не .bat-файл, а макрос на AutoIt.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 12):

Оставляя в стороне тот факт, что "убивать" процессы нехорошо и Хрому это не понравится, а также, что будут убиты ***все*** процессы Хрома, даже открытые не батником, задание выполнимо и его реализует следующий [быдло]код:

```
@echo off

set CHROME_EXE=chrome.exe
set CHROME="c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\%CHROME_EXE%"

for /l %%i in (1,1,77) do (
    call :five_sec "www.123.ru"
    call :five_sec "www.456.ru"
)
goto :eof

:five_sec
start "" %CHROME% --incognito %1
timeout 5
taskkill /t /f /im %CHROME_EXE% > nul
exit /b
```

P.S. Но учтите, что за такой подход в приличном обществе бьют канделябром по голове, причём не задавая вопросов и многократно.

Comment: А антивирус что сказал на этот код?)

Comment: @pavel Avast Internet Security. Молчит.